# Provisioning Package does not apply changes, even though it appears in Provisions folder after MDT Deployment

Tags: deployment, windows-10, provisioning, mdt, mdt-2013

I have created a provisioning package for deploying Windows 10 1709 to our organization. I have created a task in my task sequence that successfully applies the Package during Post-Install.

The desired change is a custom Start menu layout. I had originally tried to also add default local accounts and some other minor tweaks, but have since narrowed down to just the start menu for the sake of testing.

None of the customization items have been applied, and I instead get a default start menu with all of the annoying Windows Store apps.

Here is my customizations.xml from Window Config Designer (WICD):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WindowsCustomizations>
  <PackageConfig xmlns="urn:schemas-Microsoft-com:Windows-ICD-Package-Config.v1.0">
    <ID>{97a60676-1678-46f3-b45a-7aead27c9711}</ID>
    <Name>OrgName</Name>
    <Version>1.2</Version>
    <OwnerType>ITAdmin</OwnerType>
    <Rank>0</Rank>
    <Notes></Notes>
  </PackageConfig>
  <Settings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:windows-provisioning">
    <Customizations>
      <Common>
        <Policies>
          <Start>
            <StartLayout>&lt;LayoutModificationTemplate xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout" Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification"&gt;
                  &lt;LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" /&gt;
                  &lt;DefaultLayoutOverride&gt;
                    &lt;StartLayoutCollection&gt;
                      &lt;defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6"&gt;
                        &lt;start:Group Name="Communications"&gt;
                          &lt;start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Outlook 2016.lnk" /&gt;
                          &lt;start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="1" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Skype for Business 2016.lnk" /&gt;
                        &lt;/start:Group&gt;
                        &lt;start:Group Name="Tools and Tips"&gt;
                          &lt;start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="0" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" /&gt;
                          &lt;start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="2" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.Getstarted_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" /&gt;
                          &lt;start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="1" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Snipping Tool.lnk" /&gt;
                          &lt;start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="3" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" /&gt;
                        &lt;/start:Group&gt;
                        &lt;start:Group Name="Office 2016"&gt;
                          &lt;start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="1" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Excel 2016.lnk" /&gt;
                          &lt;start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="2" Row="1" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Access 2016.lnk" /&gt;
                          &lt;start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="1" Row="1" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\OneNote 2016.lnk" /&gt;
                          &lt;start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PowerPoint 2016.lnk" /&gt;
                          &lt;start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Word 2016.lnk" /&gt;
                          &lt;start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="0" Row="1" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Publisher 2016.lnk" /&gt;
                        &lt;/start:Group&gt;
                        &lt;start:Group Name="Browse the Web"&gt;
                          &lt;start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Internet Explorer.lnk" /&gt;
                          &lt;start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="2" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" /&gt;
                          &lt;start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="3" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome.lnk" /&gt;
                          &lt;start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="1" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Firefox.lnk" /&gt;
                        &lt;/start:Group&gt;
                      &lt;/defaultlayout:StartLayout&gt;
                    &lt;/StartLayoutCollection&gt;
                  &lt;/DefaultLayoutOverride&gt;
                  &lt;CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection PinListPlacement="Replace"&gt;
                    &lt;defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout&gt;
                      &lt;taskbar:TaskbarPinList&gt;
                        &lt;taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Internet Explorer.lnk"/&gt;
                    &lt;taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\File Explorer.lnk"/&gt;
                    &lt;taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Outlook 2016.lnk"/&gt;
                    &lt;taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Word 2016.lnk"/&gt;
                    &lt;taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Excel 2016.lnk"/&gt;
                    &lt;taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PowerPoint 2016.lnk"/&gt;
                      &lt;/taskbar:TaskbarPinList&gt;
                    &lt;/defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout&gt;
                  &lt;/CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection&gt;
                &lt;/LayoutModificationTemplate&gt;</StartLayout>
          </Start>
        </Policies>
      </Common>
    </Customizations>
  </Settings>
</WindowsCustomizations>
```

Here is my apply command from MDT:

```
DISM.exe /Image:%OSDisk%\ /Add-ProvisioningPackage /PackagePath:%DEPLOYROOT%\ProvPackages\DefaultPackage.ppkg
```

The following website gave me reference on how to get this far, but I have been unable to proceed and unable to find other web resources to figure out why things aren't applying:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/customize-windows-10-start-screens-by-using-provisioning-packages-and-icd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML layout you imported is broken. It appears you manually added content improperly.

You added the `<taskbar:TaskbarPinList>` section and didn't declare it at the beginning of the file:     `xmlns:taskbar="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/TaskbarLayout"`

Here is the sample XML file, and yours should follow the same format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LayoutModificationTemplate
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification"
    xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout"
    xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout"
    xmlns:taskbar="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/TaskbarLayout"
    Version="1">
  <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" StartTileGroupsColumnCount="1" />
  <DefaultLayoutOverride>
    <StartLayoutCollection>
      <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6" xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout">
        <start:Group Name="Life at a glance" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
          <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" />
          <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="4" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI" />
          <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
        </start:Group>        
      </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
    </StartLayoutCollection>
  </DefaultLayoutOverride>
    <CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>
      <defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
        <taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
          <taskbar:UWA AppUserModelID="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" />
          <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\File Explorer.lnk" />
        </taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
      </defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
    </CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/configure-windows-10-taskbar#sample-taskbar-configuration-added-to-start-layout-xml-file